# dropdown loosing indexing if missing a child element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a simple drop down menu but I am missing the indexing if the the parent div is missing the children which I am showing and hiding. This scenario comes up if there is a menu item which does not have drop down but is part of the navigation.

Here is my js

```
$('.catMain').removeClass('active');

$('.catMainHolder').mouseover(function () {
    $('.subCat').eq($(this).index()).show();
    $('.catMain').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
});
$('.catMainHolder').mouseout(function () {
    $('.subCat').eq($(this).index()).hide();
    $('.catMain').removeClass('active');
});
```

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/b7kVk/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target relative elements using `this` like - you can target the `subCat` and `catMain` elements within the hovered `catMainHolder` element.

```
$('.catMainHolder').has('.subCat').hover(function () {
    $('.subCat', this).show();
    $('.catMain', this).addClass('active');
}, function () {
    $('.subCat', this).hide();
    $('.catMain.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Z6h8n/)

Also you can target only those `catMainHolder` elements which has a `subCat` for the hover event using [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) as shown above. Or use :has() like `$('.catMainHolder:has(.subCat)').hover(..);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.catMain').removeClass('active');
$('.catMainHolder').mouseover(function () {
$(this).find('.subCat').show();
$(this).find('.catMain').addClass('active');
//$('.subCat').eq($(this).index()).show();
//$('.catMain').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
});
$('.catMainHolder').mouseout(function () {
$(this).find('.subCat').hide();
$(this).find('.catMain').removeClass('active');
//$('.subCat').eq($(this).index()).hide();
//$('.catMain').removeClass('active');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7kVk/10/)